# Droid web browser padding or margin

Tags: css, mobile, browser, width

http://m.snacknetworx.com/ goes completely 100% wide in a web browser, on an HTC Incredible there is padding and/or margin on both sides.
I created a test page to test replicate the problem:
http://m.snacknetworx.com/test.php
There's only one div with inline css:

test...

Problem being this div does not reach the edges of the HTC browser, same padding and/or margin issue, but goes 100% in a web browser.

Does anyone know how to get 100% width on a mobile browser?

Comment: Are you using a css reset file? If not, try one.

Comment: I have the following css:
html{padding:0px;margin:0px;}
body{padding:0px;margin:0px;color:#000000;font-family: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size:14px;}

Comment: Reset file made no difference: http://m.snacknetworx.com/css/reset.css

Comment: Fixed it. It was a css conflict. Thanks for your input!